# ASP.net MVC 3 changing the default edit boxes generated by controllers to a date time picker

Tags: database, datetimepicker

Thank you for taking the time to read this.. i have created a model and then created the index,create,edit,delete views using a controller. by default the system gives you views that have edit boxes  and labels like this....

```
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.LessonDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.LessonDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.LessonDate)
    </div>
```

i want to change this editor field to a date time picker. the code i have for the date tim picker is:

`<input id="demo2" type="text" size="25">
        <a href="javascript:NewCal('demo2','ddmmmyyyy',true,12)">
        <img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>`

the date time picker works and appears on the view but it does not save the date to the database i have... how do i achieve this?

thank you in advance for reading this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the name to send the information back to the controller I think all you need to do is to add the name

```
<input id="demo2" name="LessonDate" type="text" size="25">
```